# How to Read a single user's documents from a collection in React Js using Firebase 9

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web

I am trying to read documents from a current user in a collection, to display the current user's displayName after the user is successfully logged in or signed up. In React Js using Firebase 9

[Code getting data from firebase db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtNLA.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to get the document from the "users" collection

```
import {collections , where, query, getDocs} from "firebase/firestore";
```

You may use this `query` , where you can send email as a param of the user

```
export async function getUserSpecificDetails(email: string) {
  try {
    const userDetails = query(
      collection(db, "users"),
      where("email", "==", email)
    );
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(userDetails);
    return querySnapshot;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

This will return you a promise, from where you can get the data

```
getUserSpecificDetails(useEmail).then((data) => console.log(data))
```

This will return you with the JSON where you can extract from the keys like `displayName`

Comment: I tried it but, it didn't work.

Comment: @CLEARDESIGNWEBS please can you mention the error that you are getting or you can also post the output of `console.log(data)`.